# Need help on error code for a solar power inverter

Tags: electrical, solar

I have a solar array with 2 Sunpower/Sunnyboy inverters model SPR-6000m.  One of the inverters has an error that from the manual (see pic) is "Inverter Interference".  The indicator lights that blink match  the pattern in the attached pic.  The display also says "Disturbance OFFSET".  I contacted the installer and they can't come out right now because "grid tied solar systems aren't considered an 'essential service'"!   I contacted the manufacturer and after about a 45 minute call, which basically ended just being "turn it off and on again"!  (ARRG!) ended up with the same problem.

I tested the voltage on the breaker attached to the inverter and it was right at about 120-121 volts to neutral and about 240-242 across the hots.  I also pulled the cover on the inverter and double checked the voltage there and it matched.   The input voltage from the array was about 410vDC.  The other inverter is doing fine, no issues.

Our governor just extended the stay at home order until May 4, meaning I'll lose out on an entire months solar production.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Parts needed?  I'm a pretty decent electrician ( but not licensed), still I'd like to at least try to diagnose this (and hopefully fix it) without losing a month of production.

[image: error code from manual]

Comment: contact SunPower technical support at (408) 240-5500. Manual at https://docplayer.net/727096-Pv-inverter-sunpower-spr-5000m-spr-6000m-spr-7000m-spr-8000m.html

Comment: Thanks Ack, that's what I did and got a script cookie reader, after 45 min call they said that's all they could do.  Thanks for the link to the manual, but I had that which is where I copied/pasted the error code from.

Comment: Unfortunately all of these "Inverter Interference" codes simply say: "This is an internal error within the inverter. If after the system has been safely shutdown and restarted this condition persists then contact us."  That doesn't give much to go on.  Have you tried shutting down the inverter completely by isolating it both from the grid and the PV panels?  Beyond that, if this persists, it appears that this is a fault inside the unit that will need service.  Yep, that sucks!

Comment: Disconnect everything, wait an hour for everything to discharge, pull it open.

Comment: Disconnect everything, leave for at least 1 hour so it clears internal memory then reconnect and re-program, just off then on may not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike.  Earlier today I turned off the breaker to the inverter as well as the DC disconnect from the PV array.  I'll let it chill overnight and see what happens in the morning.  I'll let you know.

Comment: Turned on the inverter this morning and it still has the same problem.  So not much to do until this quarantine gets lifted.